# How to re-render data in React after the delete link has been selected?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have this React component displaying several cards (each card a separate DIV) on a page. When I click "delete" on a card, the selected card gets deleted from the database, but I can only see the change that the card dissapeared when I refresh my browser manually. Is there a way to tell the deleteRow() function to re-render the page after it gets the new JSON back?

I'm using Golang on the back-end but I don't think that matters. The "delete" link calls a handler with the DELETE method (REST API) then removes the row from the database.

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cards: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/people")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        let cards = data.map(card => {
          return (
            <div class="card">
              <p>{card.PersonFirstName}</p>
              <p>{card.PersonLastName}</p>
              <p><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(card.ID)}>Delete</a></p>
            </div>
          )
        });
        this.setState({cards: cards});
      })
  }

  deleteRow(cardID) {
    fetch("/people/" + cardID, {
      method: "delete"
    })
      .then(results => results.json());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-container">
        {this.state.cards}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

UPDATE:

This is how card looks:

```
0:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: "div"
key: null
ref: null
props:
class: "card"
children: Array(3)
0:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: "p"
key: null
ref: null
props: {children: "John"}
_owner: null
__proto__: Object
1:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: "p"
key: null
ref: null
props: {children: "Doe"}
_owner: null
__proto__: Object
2:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: "p"
key: null
ref: null
props: {children: {…}}
_owner: null
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
_owner: null
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: Side note, you can likely change your anchor link `<a ... />` to a button `<button ... />`, since it's not actually a link. Then you don't need the voided `href`.

Answer (score 0):

First way - after successful DELETE -> filter current state from deleted value and update state.

```
.then(() => {
  const cards = this.state.cards;
  const newList = cards.filter(i=> i.id !== cardID);
  this.setState({ cards:newList })
});
```

The problem is that you do not handle any response which was not successful. As we know from React documentation (we do, right?), state changes via setState enforce component to re-render.

Second way - just call cards list again as you do in componentDidMount.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. The problem is that filter doesn't seem to return the proper data since `i.id` doesn't exist. I'm still trying to figure out what I missed.

Comment: how does card looks like inside? and you ca steel use second way =)

Comment: the second way works but I need to duplicate the code, everything from `let cards = .....` until `this.setState({cards: cards});`. I have no idea how to paste the output of card here. The number of characters I can post here in the comments is limited.

Comment: you can place `card` object by editing your question. And you do not need to duplicate it -just place it to function like `getCards` and call it both in componentDidMount and in deleteRows function.

Comment: looking at your code i can imagine that `card` do not has id but has `ID`m so we can change filter predicate to `filter(i=> i.ID !== cardID)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set state after the deletion of the card in the deleteRow function

```
deleteRow(cardID) {
    fetch("/people/" + cardID, {
      method: "delete"
    })
    .then(results => {
      //results.json();
      const { cards } = this.state;
      const updatedCardList = cards.filter(card => card.id !== cardID);
      this.setState({ cards: updatedCardList })
  });
```

Comment: what do you expect to get from result.json() without `then`? And where did this code get  `updatedCardList`?